# Wordpress Theme Twenty Ten how to position the comments box above the posted comments

Tags: wordpress, comments

Good day everyone, I having this issue with regards to the comments section of my wordpress.org blog. the thing is when my blog got so much comments (around 200+) the comments is pushed down at the bottom of the blog post, until it reaches near the footer. every reader dont want this (me neither).

If any one could help me to edit to **re-position** the comments box to the top of the comments previously posted. I just want the comments boxes *(name, email, website and the comment box)* appear first before the comments posted.

It will be much easier for my readers to comments and will also be encouraged to comments.

I don't want to implement the comments pagination because i already tried it and has negative feedback from my readers.

I know its too much to ask to edit those codes below (Im sorry) but I'm not a programmer in nature :( but please kindly help me. I've been reading some tutorials but I cant understand all of them.

my bad.

hope you can help me?

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments
 * and the comment form.  The actual display of comments is
 * handled by a callback to twentyten_comment which is
 * located in the functions.php file.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
?>

            <div id="comments">
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
                <p class="nopassword"><?php _e( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view any comments.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
            </div><!-- #comments -->
<?php
        /* Stop the rest of comments.php from being processed,
         * but don't kill the script entirely -- we still have
         * to fully load the template.
         */
        return;
    endif;
?>

<?php
    // You can start editing here -- including this comment!
?>

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
            <h3 id="comments-title"><?php
            printf( _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', get_comments_number(), 'twentyten' ),
            number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<em>' . get_the_title() . '</em>' );
            ?></h3>

<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older Comments', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            </div> <!-- .navigation -->
<?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

            <ol class="commentlist">
                <?php
                    /* Loop through and list the comments. Tell wp_list_comments()
                     * to use twentyten_comment() to format the comments.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then you can
                     * define twentyten_comment() and that will be used instead.
                     * See twentyten_comment() in twentyten/functions.php for more.
                     */
                    wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyten_comment' ) );
                ?>
            </ol>

<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older Comments', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            </div><!-- .navigation -->
<?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

<?php else : // or, if we don't have comments:

    /* If there are no comments and comments are closed,
     * let's leave a little note, shall we?
     */
    if ( ! comments_open() ) :
?>
    <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( '', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; // end ! comments_open() ?>

<?php endif; // end have_comments() ?>

<?php comment_form(); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

Answer (score 0):

the function your looking for is `<?php comment_form(); ?>` also check the comments.php template and you can edit how there rendered on all posts from one central location.